# How to do cross-application with serverless AWS

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudfront, serverless-framework, aws-serverless

I have two different applications in AWS, deployed by two serverless config files.
In the first one, I need to read the data from the DynamoDB of the second one.

serverless.yml n°1 :

```
service:
  name: stack1
app: app1
org: globalorg
```

serverless.yml n°2 :

```
service:
  name: stack2
app: app2
org: globalorg
```

If I put the 2 services in same app, I can access to the 2nd one with a line like this in iamRoleStatements :

```
Resource:
    - ${output::${param:env}::stack2.TableArn}
```

But if they are not in the same app, I have "Service not found" error when I try to deploy.
How can I do this cross-application communication ?
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You will need to provide the actual ARN of the table now that this stack is not part of your app you cannot reference its components. Try something like this

```
custom:
  table: 
    tableArn: "<insert-ARN-of-resource-here>"
```

```
IamRoleStatements:
      Resource: ${self:custom.table.tableArn}
```